# randomly split data in n groups?

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures

I am currently trying to write code for splitting a given data into a number of groups.

The groups should be created randomly and they should encompass together the entire data.

So let's suppose there's an array `A` of eg. `shape` = `(3, 3, 3)` that has 27 root elements `e`:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

I want to create `n` groups such that `g1 & g2 & ... & gn` will "add up" to the original array `A`.

I shuffled `A` as following

```
def shuffle(array):

    shuf = array.ravel()
    np.random.shuffle(shuf)

    return np.reshape(shuf, array.shape)
```

But how do I create `n` groups (`n < e`) randomly?

Thanks!

Leo

Comment: Do you need particular shape for the output? Or can it be just one dimensional?

Comment: The output should be `n` different groups, but the shape of each individual group doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not so elegant, the following code will spread the array to n group with ensuring each group having at least one element, and spread the rest randomly.

```py
import numpy as np

def shuffle_and_group(array, n):
    shuf = array.ravel()
    np.random.shuffle(shuf)
    shuf = list(shuf)

    groups = []
    for i in range(n):  # ensuring no empty group
        groups.append([shuf.pop()])

    for num in shuf:  # spread the remaining
        groups[np.random.randint(n)].append(num)
    return groups

array = np.arange(15)
print(shuffle_and_group(array, 9))
```

In case you worry about the time, the code will have time complexity of O(e) where e is the number of elements.

Comment: I managed to pull this answer on my own but it is highly dependent on the `shape` and I don't want this.

Let me wrap it differently. 

I have the following array which has 27 root elements `e`: 

`array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])`;
How do I create `n` groups (`n < e`) randomly considering this?

Comment: Do you mean that the length of each group is random also? If yes, how do you want it (or the distribution) to be, is it always floor(n/e) except the last one(technically not random lenght)?

Comment: Yes. For eg. , the following function I wrote is close to what I need but it creates empty groups just to satisfy `n`. I want the function to pick the length on its own just so that `e` falls randomly in `n` groups as long as `n` < `e`.

`def groups(array, n)` >>> `array = shuffle(array)` >>> `return np.array_split(array, n)`

Comment: I have just edited the answer, is that what you need?